# Methods of solving this exam FM problem with geometric-investments.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

The problem I am working on is as follows.

> Matthew makes a series of payments at the beginning of each year for $20$ years.  The first payment is $100$.  Each subsequent payment through the tenth year increases by $5\%$ from the previous payment.  After the tenth payment, each payment decreases by $5\%$ from the previous payment.  Calculate the present value of these payments at the time the first payment is made using an annual effective rate of $7\%$.

In this exam, time is of essence and the way I tried to solve this problem took much longer and I wanted to and what is worse, did not get the answer.

What I tried was the following.

$$\begin{align}
PV  &= 100(1+(1.05v)+(1.05v)^2+ \cdots +(1.05v)^9)+100(1.05^9v^{10})(.95+.95^2v+ \cdots +.95^{10}v^{9}) \\
&=\frac{100}{105v}(\alpha+\alpha^2+ \cdots +\alpha^{10})+100(1.05v)^9(\beta + \beta^2+ \cdots +\beta^{10})\\
&=\frac{100}{105v}a_{\overline{10}\rceil j}+100(1.05v)^9a_{\overline{10}\rceil k}\\
& \approx 1308.4
\end{align}$$

where $\alpha=1.05v, \ \beta=.95v$ and $j=\alpha^{-1}-1, \ k=\beta^{-1}-1$.

In retrospect, I feel as though using the geometric sum would have been a safer route to take rather than the annuity immediate or due. But since my calculations will end up being the same I am thinking that I missed something (the answer is supposedly 1385)

Can someone help me out?  I did not quite understand the solution that the book provides for it uses some formula that I am not fully familiar with.

Comment: Is first payment made now or a year from now? If it is a year from now then that could be mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an annuity of $n$ periods (starting a period from now, thus $n$ payments) with initial payment $A$ that grows at $g$ per period we have that PV of this annuity with effective rate $r$

$$PV=\frac{A}{r-g}\left(1-\left(\frac{1+g}{1+r}\right)^n\right)$$

Note: This essentially finds present value of payments one period before first. With this it should be much easier to find answer

Comment: Ah, I see. This is actually very helpful because the expression looks similar to the explanation in the book.  I will try to derive this formula in order to remember it from now on.  Thank you.

Comment: Yea Ill be taking fm too this February. Good luck with your studies. Yea make sure to find little "tools" like this that you can just apply during test. To do this in financial calculator set PMT=(1+g)A, I/Y=(r-g)/(1+g), N=n then CMPT PV

Comment: Thank you.  I will take it April. Good luck with yours.

Comment: Also try memorizing the how finance calculator calculates FV and PV not by if it's annuity immediate or due. But rather what period it is it (is it at that period, before, or after)

Answer (score 1):

Your cash flow, written out, is correct.  However, your simplification and expression in terms of actuarial notation is not quite optimal because the formula reverts to the usual finite geometric series sum anyway:  Let $\alpha = 1.05v = 1/(j+1)$, $\beta = 0.95v = 1/(k+1)$ be the equivalent present value discount factors.  Then $$\begin{align*}  PV &= 100(1 + \alpha + \cdots + \alpha^9) + 100 (1.05)^9 (0.95) v^{10} (1 + \beta + \cdots + \beta^9) \\ &= 100 a_{\overline{10}\rceil j} + 95 (1.05)^9 v^{10} a_{\overline{10}\rceil k} \\ &= 100 \frac{1 - \alpha^{10}}{1 - \alpha} +  95 (1.05)^9 v^{10} \frac{1 - \beta^{10}}{1- \beta}. \end{align*}$$  Sure, you could use a BA II financial calculator to calculate the annuities-immediate, but why in this case?

The answer, to more significant digits, is $1384.645\ldots$.

Comment: Thank you, very much. I am more comfortable with scientific calculators such as TI 30X II but because I want to be an actuary, I wanted to learn how to use a BA II+.  So, sometimes it's easier to get the annuity immediate.  But in this problem it clearly makes it more time consuming and risky, so I probably will stick with algebraically simpler methods.